# Rails query for instances outside association condition

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Product model association:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes
  has_many :liking_users, through: :likes, source: :user
end
```

I want to find all Products which the current user has not liked.

Basically, all products except `Product.joins(:liking_users).where(users: {id: current_user.id})`

Can you think of an efficient query for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Product.joins(:liking_users).where.not(users: {id: current_user.id})
```

Comment: but, this will not return products, which are not liked by any user.